# Passing and Retrieving Arguments Flutter - Error: Property 'settings' cannot be accessed on 'ModalRoute<Object?>?' because it is potentially null

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, arguments

May I know what's wrong with my code below?

I try to send some argument from login screen to home screen,
but all I get is error :
Error: Property 'settings' cannot be accessed on 'ModalRoute<Object?>?' because it is potentially null.

So my code design is, from my main.dart is calling route_generator which saving all the route, main.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigation/constants/app_color.dart';
import 'package:navigation/route_generator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'My Apps',
    theme: ThemeData(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Constant.buttonPrimaryColor,
    )),
    initialRoute: '/loginScreen',
    onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
    ));
}
```

route_generator.dart that maintains all the route :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigation/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:navigation/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:navigation/screens/about_screen.dart';

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/loginScreen':
        return MaterialPageRoute (builder: (context) => LoginScreen());
      case '/homeScreen':
        return MaterialPageRoute (builder: (context) => HomeScreen()); 
      case '/aboutScreen':
        return MaterialPageRoute (builder: (context) => AboutScreen());
      default:
        return _errorRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route<dynamic> _errorRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('ERROR'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Page not found!'),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Then some services.dart that navigate based on API response (sent arguments here), so basically i try to redirect to Home Screen from this Login Screen, and from this login screen i try to sent some arguments into Home Screen and try to receive it and show it in the screen, put some dummy data here with name and email :

```
if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    print('Response status code : ' + response.statusCode.toString());    
    print('response body : ' + response.body);
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/homeScreen', arguments: {
                 'name':'Johny',
                 'email':'johny@johny.com',
    });
      } else {
        print('Response status code : ' + response.statusCode.toString());      
        print('exception is : ' + response.body);
        throw Exception('Failed to login.');
      }
```

This is the home_screen.dart that throws an error from the flutter :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigation/constants/app_color.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  final Map<String, dynamic> map = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Text("Home"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Welcome to Apps",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "Hi, xxx",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/aboutScreen');
                },
                child: Text(
                  "About",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                  ),
                ),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Constant.buttonPrimaryColor),
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Constant.buttonPrimaryColor)
                    )
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Logout",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                  ),
                ),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Constant.buttonPrimaryColor),
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Constant.buttonPrimaryColor)
                    )
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I try to follow some of the tutorials out there,
and in the RouteGenerator I already pass the RouteSettings,
try to read a couple of times but still confuse,
can somebody explain and show me how to pass and show the arguments?

Full log :

```
lib/screens/home_screen.dart:14:59: Error: Property 'settings' cannot be accessed on 
'ModalRoute<Object?>?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'ModalRoute' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart').
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try accessing using ?. instead.
  final Map<String, dynamic> map = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
                                                          ^^^^^^^^
lib/screens/home_screen.dart:14:68: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262655/flutter-get-passed-arguments-from-navigator-in-widgets-states-initstate 
 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66834506/parameter-is-null-instead-of-an-id-with-modalroute-of , https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 3):

The error tips means that some params may be null.So you should use more safe access method.The following code may be help you fix this issue.

```
  final Map<String, dynamic> map = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments;
```

Answer (score 0):

i try this and it work

```
final Object? data = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments;
```